# telegram bot api，how to only send replyMarkup and not send message reply?

Tags: telegram-bot

[my bot have a pin reply message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rKnF.png)

[other bot not a pin message ,only have reply button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILlCK.jpg)

this is my code:

```
  val locale = botUser.languageCode?.let { Locale.forLanguageTag(it) } ?: Locale.ENGLISH
                    val welcomeStart = messageSource.getMessage("welcome.start", locale, botUser.id).orElse(I18nConstants.constants)
                    val sendMessage= SendMessage().apply {
                        this.chatId=chat?.id.toString()
                        this.text=welcomeStart
                    }
                    sendMessage.replyMarkup= ReplyMarkUpHelper.getStartReplyKeyboardMarkup()
                absSender?.executeAsync(sendMessage)
```

how can i fix pin message,only return the replyMarkup to user?

Comment: i get it. other bot buttons use in private chat. i use in group chat.